# vector of random variables and conditional probability problem?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I truly don't know how to approach the following problem

> > Consider a sequence of events identically distributed and
> > independent with probability of success $p$.  Let $S_i$ be the
> > success of the i-th event. Denote $X_1$ the time at which the
> > first success happened and $X_1+X_2$ the time when the second
> > success happened. Express the events $\{X_1=k, X_2=\ell\}$ for $ 
> >  k,\ell \in \mathbb{N}$ in terms of $S_i$ and prove that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.

I think that $S_i$ is distributed as a Binomial(N,p), where $N$ is the number of times event was done, and $X_1=\sum_{i=1}^{N} S_1$. Is this correct? Any Hint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By what I understand from the exercise, $S_i$ is actually a Bernoulli random variable, so $P(S_i = 1)=p$ and $P(S_i = 0)=1-p$, where $1$ is success and $0$ is failure. So, $\sum^n_{i=1} S_i \sim Binomial(n,p)$, but not $S_i$.

Now, for the $X$'s. Note that $X_1$ is the smallest index such that $S_i$ is a success.

$$X_1(w)= \inf\{n : \sum^n_{i=1}S_i(w) \geq 1 
\}$$

$X_2$ is similar to $X_1$, and it represents the number of trials until the second success.
$$
X_2(w)= \inf\{n : \sum^n_{i=X_1(w)+1}S_i(w) \geq 1 
\}
$$

The distribution of $X_1 + X_2$ is a Negative binomial, which is given by
$$
P(X_1+X_2 = k)=
{k+2-1\choose k}p ^2(1-p)^k
$$

Since the Negative binomial is identical to the sum of i.i.d Geometric random variables, then $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.

One can also show the independence by noting that
$$\{X_1=k,X_2=l\} = \{S_1=0,...,S_k=1,S_{k+1}=0,...,S_{k+l}=1\}
$$

Since $S$ are independent, it is clear that so are $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Comment: Interesting, although I was thinking that for example the event $\{X_1= t\}=\{ S_0=0, \dots, S_{t}=1\}$ and so $P(X=t)=P(S_0=0)...P(S_t=1)=pq^t$ so yep it looks like a geometric one.

Comment: That is it. And the sum of two geometrics give you the neg. binomial.

Comment: I complemented the answer, see now if you find clearer the reason they are independent.

Comment: another question, then $P(X_2=k)=p(1-p)^{k-1}$?

Comment: Yep, that’s it.

Comment: Just to follow, therefore $P(X_1=j,X_2=k)=p^2(1-p)^{j+k-1}$? as that's the product of each marginal. ?

Comment: Yeah, that would be it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110147/discussion-between-lilian-hernandez-and-davi-barreira).